# Travel to Germany with a UK student visa

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, international-travel

I am an Indian, currently residing in the UK with a student visa.  I would like to visit a few European countries including Germany, Norway and Sweden. Do I need a Schengen visa for this?

Answer (score 2):

[UK Council for International Student Affairs](http://www.ukcisa.org.uk/International-Students/Immigration-/Other-immigration-matters/Schengen-visas/#) addresses this very question:

> If you are not a European Economic Area national and want to travel to Europe, you may be required to apply for a Schengen visa before you travel.

Given the fact that you require a Schengen visa to enter the area you will need to get one.  The UK student visa doesn't entitle you for Schengen visit.